# How to speed up when I use two for loops in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

I have two datasets (A, B) about coordinates. For every spot in A (a), I need to find a spot in B (b) that is closet to a. So, I need two for loops: one is for every spot in A and the other is for every spot in B. The problem is these two datasets are too long. A has about 40000 rows and B has 140000 rows.

Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myChokePosition)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(myBusinessLociType)) {
       d <- distm(c(myChokePosition$lon[i],myChokePosition$lat[i]),
                  c(myBusinessLociType$lon[j],myBusinessLociType$lat[j]),
                  fun = distHaversine)
       if (d < myChokePosition$distance[i]) {
           myChokePosition$distance[i] <- d
           myChokePosition$businesstype[i] <- as.character(myBusinessLociType$longname[j])
        }
     }
     cat(i,"\n")
  }
```

In R, this is going to take for ever. How can I speed it up?

Comment: You should consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com ; this is what that SE site is for.

Comment: If you can provide sample data for both datasets (using `dput`), then we can help. Otherwise it's very hard to do anything with the code you provided.

Comment: Take a look at the `foreach` package [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/) to vectorize the computation. You need two nested `foreach`s with the "kernel" being `distm` to return `d` for each `i` and `j`. Use `rbind` as the `.combine` option in the outer `foreach` to get `d[i,j]` as the result of the two `foreach`. Then, use `apply` with `which.min` to get the `j` that minimizes `d` for each row of `d[i,j]`. Then use this 'j' to retrieve both the min `d` and the desired `myBusinessLociType$longname`.

Comment: Thanks!, It is a good way. I found that I can do this using nested foreach. Now I am just not sure how much this can speed up